# Unity Raycast results different on two devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I use the following codes to detect which UI element is the player pointing. It works well in Unity Editor, on one of my Android phone, but failed on a second Android phone.

```
public static T RaycastOnFirstPointed<T>(EventSystem eventSystem, GraphicRaycaster raycaster)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        if (Input.touches == null || Input.touches.Length == 0) return default;
    }
    var m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
    m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results); // On the 2nd phone the results.length is 0
    foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
    {
        var component = result.gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
        if (component != null)
        {
            return component;
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

This method is called within a `IEndDragHandler.OnEndDrag` method. I tried to debug it on the 2nd Android phone, and saw the `results.length` is 0 after `Raycast` was executed.(it should be > 0 since I ended my drag on several overlapped UI elements, and it is > 0 on the 1st phone, not sure why the 2nd phone is different)

I don't have any clue where should I go from here to find the problem. Please show me some directions, thank you!

More info:
Phone 1: MI 8 Lite, OS: MIUI 10.3
Phone 2: MI 9, OS: MIUI 10.2.35

============Update===========

Reason found:
When `IEndDragHandler.OnEndDrag` is triggered, the `Input.mousePosition` has different value on the two devices. 1st Phone has the touch position from the last frame, while the 2nd phone seems clears that value, and it has a very large wrong value. I'm working on how to solve this in a proper way. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As I updated in the question, this problem is caused by wrong `Input.mousePosition` value on different devices. So I updated the `RaycastOnFirstPointed` method as follows:

```
public static T RaycastOnFirstPointed<T>(EventSystem eventSystem, GraphicRaycaster raycaster, PointerEventData eventData = null)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        if (Input.touches == null || Input.touches.Length == 0) return default;
    }
    var m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
    if (eventData == null)
    {
        m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else
    {
        m_PointerEventData.position = eventData.position;
    }
    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);
    foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
    {
        var component = result.gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
        if (component != null)
        {
            return component;
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

When call this method within `OnEndDrag`, pass in the `PointerEventData` that unity provides and use its position.